# blazor CSS isolation: class as parameter to child

Tags: css, blazor-webassembly

How can I get css isolation to work when the class is added as an argument to child component? In the code below I would expect the child component to be blue, however, this is not happening.

Parent.razor

```
<div class="firstLayer">
  <Child Class="secondLayer"/>
</div>
```

Child.razor

```
<div class="@Class">
  Whaterver
</div>

@code {
   [Parameter] public string Class {get;set}
}
```

Parent.razor.css

```
::deep firstLayer secondLayer{
  color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `deep` should be on the second level, like:
`firstLayer ::deep secondLayer`

or use the CSS on the child.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but this was indeed the solution, In my code the firstLayer was sometimes in parent and sometimes in child, so it was a bit of a struggle to get it everywhere correct.

Comment: It apparently also requires to be nested inside a <div>, this was not always the case in my code.